# Abstract name for one side of a Friend/Follow relationship

Tags: naming-conventions

I have a model where a `User` represents the user using the application and each `User` has `friend`s and `follower`s (identical to twitter relationship paradigm) which are just references to other 'User's with information like `dateAdded`, `userId` etc

I've found my `friend` and `follower` model classes have similar enough high level concepts to justify an abstract base, but I can't think of a name for one side of a friend relationship that is specific to this friend model and isn't too general.

So far my best candidate I am considering is `SocialGraphVertex`. Perhaps `SocialGraphLeaf` is more accurate or `RelationshipLeaf` is less of a mouthful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an edge in a graph, `RelationshipEdge` is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like `RelatedPerson`.

The key concern when introducing names for such base classes is that whatever name you choose must be compliant with the *is-a* relations you introduce. For instance, the `RelatedPerson` sort of works out sense a `friend` *is a* `RelatedPerson` and a `follower` *is a* `RelatedPerson`.

It would be easier to give a good suggestion if you included a few properties of the base class.